# react context hoc, nested arrow function vs. normal nested function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

So basically I've got this function here:

```
export function withContext () {
  return function withComponent (Component) {
    return function contextComponent (props) {
      return (
        <Consumer>
          {context => <Component {...props} {...context} />}
        </Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

this one is working without a problem when im wrapping my component's
with it.

I thought yeh why not try to switch to es8 syntax instead to make it more readable. So i wrote my function like this:

```
export const withContext = () => Component => props => (
  <Consumer>
   {context => <Component {...props} {...context} />}
  </Consumer>
)
```

And this didn't work at all. The following error message did drop:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function
```

I use both functions this way:

```
export default withContext()(MyComponent)
```

I am now a little bit confused, because i thought the nested arrow function was kind of the same as the function above.

Comment: Two snippets are essentially the same, unless you refer to named functions, and you don't. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Alexander! Interesting, it should work the same. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: ok i created an example, you can find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pjy29x1p3j). The funny think is now i get a different error message in CodeSandbox which says: `(0 , _Provider.withContextArrow) is not a function`. I also have two buttons there one of them is wrapped with the arrow function hoc the other one in a normal way and both of them are working totally fine. To say so my on my own application i'am using next.js.